# how to gracefully halt the slideup and slidedown function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width : 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
p{
   width : 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;

}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  $("div").hide();

  var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   para[0].onmouseover = function(){
       $("div").stop().slideDown('slow');
   }

   para[0].onmouseout = function(){
       $("div").stop().slideUp('slow');
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>show div</p>
<div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code, actually I want to halt the previous animation when I actually mouse in or mouse out the paragraph. But I realize that when I mouse in and out quickly, at some point, when the mouse enter the paragraph again it will only slide down to the height at which it stopped the previous time. The solution is to set the second argument of `stop` to `true`. Tthen the current animation not only stops, but also jumps immediately to the final value. It is actually not the effect intended. How should I solve this??

Comment: You have to use the versions of the jQuery functions that take objects. Specify a `progress()` function and call `stop()` at the point where you want the animation to stop.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dvaJD/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6nBvT/ it is what are you looking for